# how to take average for Varchar data type

Tags: sql, sql-server

one of my column in my table is of type varchar. which contains hexadecimal values.
i need to take average for particular month .
the below is my query. please help me how to change the code to achieve it.

```
select avg(hex) from history where Date between '2016-11-01' and '2017-11-29' group by Date;
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Which dbms are you using? (Your current query is product specific.)

Comment: sqlserver . yes my query is product specific

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `CAST` to `DateTime`

```
 SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("SELECT Top 1 CAST(TimeStamp AS DATETIME) as TimeStamp  FROM HistoryReport ", conn);
```

[CAST](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/cast-and-convert-transact-sql)

**For example**

```
SELECT CAST('2017/10/10' AS DATETIME)
```

The filed should be a `DateTime` string or they will be error

**EDIT**

A small example for you.

The keyPoint is  `command.ExecuteReader()` get the SQL Query Collection.

```
string commandText = "SELECT Top 1 CAST(TimeStamp AS DATETIME) as TimeStamp  FROM HistoryReport ";
string connectionString = "your Connection string";
using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
{
    SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(commandText, conn);
    try
    {
        connection.Open();
        SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
        while (reader.Read())
        {
            DateTime date = reader[0] as DateTime;
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
    }
}
```

[SqlCommand](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/9kcbe65k(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: can  u  please explain clearly that  how CAST works and tell me whether the DATETIME can be used as a argument in any one of the function @D-Shih

Comment: Converts an expression of one data type to  `CAST([field] AS [you want dataType]) `

Comment: i need to store this command value to another variable of type DateTime .can u please help me, how i need to change my code to achieve it

Comment: Could you show me the sample data from `TimeStamp` field?
Did you want to store  `TimeStamp`  as datetime value to c# code?

Comment: sample data from TimeStamp="2016-02-29 00:01:01.000 ". yes i want to store TimeStamp as datetime value to c# code

Comment: Ok!! You need to edit the question and put the full code  from C#.